# Does bubble tea have any health benefits?

Tags: sugar, tea

There are lots of bubble tea shops around where I live and so I get bubble teas pretty often.  But the drinks are usually pretty sweet.

Do these bubble teas actually have any health benefits?  Or are the drinks pretty much as bad as drinking soda?

Comment: this would depend on how much sugar is in the drink. It could very well be as bad as drinking soda